# Fetch columns by matching them to another data's row value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I am trying to fetch columns from one dataframe  whose column name matches the value given in another dataframe's rows.

Table 1

```
Number Green Blue Black White 
1        10   11   0     13
2        21   14   5     12
3        24   24   11    0
```

Table 2

```
X L1       L2      L3      L4 
1 Black    White              
2 Green    Black 
3 Blue     Green           White
```

For each row of table 2, I want to subset table 1 by selecting columns whose name matches the content of table 2 (cols 2:4).

For X = 2, this would be:

```
Number Green Black  
1        10    0  
2        21    5  
3        24    11
```

How can I get that?

I tried `table1[, which(names(table1) %in% (table2[1, c(2:5)]))]`

Comment: For single column: `df1[intersect(colnames(df1), df2$L2)]`  and for general solution: `lapply(2:5, function(x)  df1[intersect(colnames(df1), df2[,x])])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` method which converts the data frames to long format, joins and finally spreads to give the desired output. The `split` method at the end just creates a list with each element corresponding to each `X`, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
 gather(var, val, -Number) %>% 
 left_join(df2 %>% gather(val, var, -X) %>% select(-val), by = 'var') %>% 
 spread(var, val) %>% 
 split(.$X)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
>   Number X Black Blue Green White
> 1      1 1     0   NA    NA    13
> 4      2 1     5   NA    NA    12
> 7      3 1    11   NA    NA     0
>
> $`2`
>   Number X Black Blue Green White
> 2      1 2     0   NA    10    NA
> 5      2 2     5   NA    21    NA
> 8      3 2    11   NA    24    NA
>
> $`3`
>   Number X Black Blue Green White
> 3      1 3    NA   11    10    13
> 6      2 3    NA   14    21    12
> 9      3 3    NA   24    24     0
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question regarding your code. Wanted to understand what "var" and "val" would be and why do you eliminate number and X?

Comment: When you convert a table from wide to long, then that means that you are collapsing the column names to one column ('var') and the values of each column to another ('val'). So var and val are just the names I chose to give. You can name them anything you like. What do you mean *why do I eliminate number and X*? Both, number and X are there

Comment: @Sotos I think OP is just confused about the `gather` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard-coded but might help:

```
Columns<-apply(Table2,2,function(x) match(x,names(Table1)))
Columns<-as.data.frame(Columns)
Columns[is.na(Columns)]<-0
apply(Columns,1,function(x) Table1[,x])
```

This gives us(truncated):

```
[[1]]
  Black White
1     0    13
2     5    12
3    11     0

[[2]]
  Green Black
1    10     0
2    21     5
3    24    11
```